# prove that $a^2 + b^2 +c^2 < d^2 + e^2$ with the following rules:

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Please help, I've been trying to prove this for a week now.
$$
A + b + c = f\\
d + e = f\\
A,b,c,d,e,f \in \mathbb{N}
$$

prove that if a,b,c,d,e, and f are not equal to 0 then for all values of $f$, there will exist a value for $d$ and a value for $e$ such that, for all values of $A,b$, and $c$, $$(A^2 + b^2 + c^2 < d^2 + e^2)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $d=f-1$ and $e=1$. Then for all positive values of $A,b,c$ we have :
$$A^2+b^2+c^2 = (a+b+c)^2 -2(ab+ac+bc) \leq f^2-2f < (f-1)^2+1^2$$

Because $(ab+bc+ac)\geq a+b+c \geq f$ ( $a,b,c\geq 1$ because they are positive integers)

Comment: Now I have an answer accordingly